# Does the Level I Multiverse theory violate the 2nd Law of Thermodynamics?

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy, multiverse

As far as I can understand, the [Level I Multiverse theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiverse#Level_I:_An_extension_of_our_Universe) is based on the idea of eternal inflation. It states that considering an eternally inflating and expanding universe, an infinite amount of possibilities or parallel universes will pop up essentially.

But doesn't the 2nd Law of Thermodynamics limit our universe to the amount of energy it has? Entropy will increase no matter what. For an infinite amount of parallel universes, wouldn't you correspondingly need an infinite source of energy?

Comment: Energy is not conserved in an inflating universe

Answer (score 2):

Energy conservation does not even hold in a classical expanding universe, without parallel worlds. For example, the redshift of photons due to the cosmic expansion is actually a loss of energy.